How to configure NERDTree to show dotfiles by default with SpaceVim?
I'm using NeoVim v0.9.5  with the SpaceVim v2.3.0 configuration Framework. I'd like to have NerdTree to show dotfiles by default.
This works by adding let g:NERDTreeShowHidden = 1 to ~/.SpaceVim/bundle/nerdtree/autoload/nerdtree.vim, but that violates the SpaceVim framework, where the ~/.Spacevim folder shouldn't be used for custom settings.
The Spacevim way is to use custom functions in e.g. ~/.SpaceVim.d/autoload/my_own_defs.vim which is then sourced by ~/.SpaceVim.d/init.toml.
So, e.g.
function! my_own_defs#before() abort 

    " ----- Enable line numbers in nerdtree -----
    let g:NERDTreeShowLineNumbers = 1

endfunction

works fine, whereas the entry let g:NERDTreeShowHidden = 1 doesn't.
I've also tried the #after() function, or using ~/.SpaceVim.d/init.toml, as I tried different versions of neovim and spacevim.
The only working way for me currently is to use ~/.SpaceVim/bundle/nerdtree/autoload/nerdtree.vim directly, which then is getting overwritten by a following spacevim update with git pull.
Anyone has any idea?

Use spacevim's official support channels.
